Does $A$-fold choice imply $|A| + |A| = |A|$ and $|A|\cdot |A| = |A|$?
Let $A$ be an infinite set. Then Zorn's lemma can be used to conclude that $A\times\{0, 1\}$, $A\times A$ and $A$ are all equinumerous (a proof is presented here). However, I am aware that for $A$ countably infinite, one doesn't need the full [any] choice conclude this; only countable choice is sufficient. This makes me wonder if one can get away with just $A$-fold choice1 rather than the full force of Zorn's lemma.

1By $A$-fold choice, I mean getting a choice function on $A$ (and thus on any set in bijection with $A$).

For $A$ countably infinite you don't need any amount of choice to conclude that. What does "a choice function on $A$" mean? If you mean there is a choice function on $P(A)\setminus {\emptyset}$ (or equivalently $A$ is well-orderable), then yes, that's sufficient (and this also implies no choice is required for $A$ countably infinite, though there are simpler arguments for that case).

If (presumably) $ℕ$-fold choice is countable choice, then $A$-fold choice should mean that $A$ is projective, i.e. that any $A$-indexed collection of nonempty sets has a choice function.

@spaceisdarkgreen You are quite correct. I was having "countable union of countables is countable" in the back of my mind when I wrote it. Nevertheless, if I am not mistaken, you claim that $A$-fold choice (which you correctly describe) is sufficient to deduce that $A\times{0, 1}$, $A\times A$ and $A$ are equinumerous. But doesn't this violate Asaf's negative answer?

@Atom Asaf's negative answer takes "$A$-fold choice" to mean what he said in the second sentence of his answer. If, on the other hand, "$A$-fold choice" means that there's a choice function picking an element from every nonempty subset of $A$, then the answer is positive.

@Atom no, Asaf’s interpretation of what “$A$-fold choice” means is different from mine. His is more consonant with the name (and with what was perhaps an implied analogy with countable choice). Mine is more consonant with the description “getting a choice function on $A$”.

(Asaf's definition is that $A$ is projective, while spaceisdarkgreen's definition is that $A$ is choice.)

@spaceisdarkgreen Ah, my bad! I now understand the difference between these versions of choice. Can you show how your version of choice is sufficient to conclude that $A\times{0, 1}$, $A\times A$ and $A$ are all equinumerous?

If $A$ is choice then it is well-orderable, hence in bijection with some cardinal number; then apply https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardinal_Product_Equal_to_Maximum.

It isn't quite clear what "$A$-fold choice" mean. Presumably, this means that "Every family indexed by $A$ admits a choice function". In this case, the answer is negative. This was shown in the following paper,

Asaf Karagila, Realizing realizability results with classical constructions. Bull. Symb. Log. 25 (4), 429-445 (2019) (ZBL07167381, arXiv:1905.08202).

There are a number of examples where models of $\sf ZF+DC_\kappa+AC_X$ holds, for some $X$ such that $X^2$ is strictly larger than $X$ itself. (This is made explicit in Section 4.4).
